# Doctrine How to Change collation for only one column

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, character-encoding

In doctrine I would like change the collation of only one column. I set charset and collation in mysql's column using this line:

```
ALTER TABLE campagne
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
MODIFY message TEXT
  CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL;
```

For doctrine i use annotation and I see one method :
annotation for the table:

```
/**
 * Campagne
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="campagne", options={"collate"="utf8mb4_unicode_ci", "charset"="utf8mb4"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\campagneRepository")
 */
```

and column's annotation :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="string", length=1000, nullable=true, options={"collation":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
 */
private $message;
```

But it seems doesn't work.

Anyone have this kind of problem? Or maybe I'm wrong in my thinking?

Comment: did you do a `doctrine:schema:update --force`?

Comment: It doesn't work cause doctrine tell you : "you can't use these annotation for configure database"
The probleme is not with mysql configuration